# JavaScript after Form Handling spit content on page

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I'm trying to make a website where you enter your name and it gets spit out on the page. I want to do this using JavaScript.

**HTML:**

```
    <div id='errormsg'></div>
    <form action='' method='post' onsubmit="formSubmit();">
        <input id='name' type='text' placeholder='Slogan here...'>
        <input id='submit' type='submit' value='Generate'>
    </form>
    <div id="nameContent"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
function formSubmit() {
var formName, formError, nameSentence;
formError = document.getElementById("errormsg");
formName = document.getElementById("name");
nameSentence = document.getElementById("nameContent");
if (formName == "") {
    formError.innerHTML = "Put your name in!";
} else if (formName > 20) {
    formName.innerHTML = "Max. 20 characters";
} else {
    nameSentence.innerHTML = formName ;
    }
}
```

The first problem is that it doesn't give me any result. I'm in the learning process of JavaScript so please tell me what is wrong. The divs `errormsg` and `nameContent` are on the page. So that is not the problem.
**I want this to happen without jQuery just plain JavaScript**

Comment: reverse your variables and value assignments. Put variables on left side of '=' sign and values on right

Comment: I've changed it in my code but it doesn't work. I'll update this post too @HimanshuTanwar

Comment: Where is an element with id `errormsg`? Please show that part of HTML

Comment: where is the 'formName' variable assigned a value?

Comment: @AxelAmthor updated it.

Comment: @HimanshuTanwar the formName is assigned to the input with the id name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have noticed that few variables are not needed.
The value of widget could be accessed by Id so formName was removed.

```js
function formSubmit() {
  var formError = document.getElementById("errormsg");
  var nameContent = document.getElementById("nameContent");
  var formSlogan = document.getElementById("name").value;
  if (formSlogan == "") {
    formError.innerHTML = "Put your name in!";
  }
  else if (formSlogan.length > 20) {
    formError.innerHTML = "Max. 20 characters";
  }
  else {
    formError.innerHTML = "";
    nameContent.innerHTML = formSlogan;
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<div id='errormsg'></div>
<form action='' method='post' onsubmit="formSubmit();">
  <input id='name' type='text' placeholder='Slogan here...'>
  <input id='submit' type='submit' value='Generate'>
</form>
<div id="nameContent"></div>
```

Comment: This did help but I have the next problem... When I submit the form. It shows the name but only for a split second and then it disappears? What does cause this? Or do I need to do this different. Because in your code snippet it works fine. My JavaScript is on a different file.

Comment: The submitted form by default reloads the page. If you want to break that behavior return `false` from the `formSubmit()` method. The form wont be submitted.

Comment: Where do I need to put it? Can you edit your answer?

Comment: At places the method fails (or at the end) and return true on success.

Comment: It didn't work. Because you have to add return in the HTML at the form onsubmit. Now it works fine! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong on basic levels. You use asignment (`=`) operator in a wrong way - you try to assign variable to value, not value to variable. Please reverse your assignments:

```
function formSubmit() {
  var formName, formError, nameSentence;
  formError = document.getElementById("errormsg");
  formName = document.getElementById("name");
  nameSentence = document.getElementById("nameContent");

  if(formName) {
    if (formName.value === "") {
      formError.innerHTML = "Put your name in!";
    } else if (formName.value.length > 20) {
      errormsg.innerHTML = "Max. 20 characters";
    } else {
      nameSentence.innerHTML = formName.value ;
    }
  }
}
```

As for HTML, you don't have to use form tag if you don't want the page to refresh, you can use `onclick()` event:

```
  <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Slogan here...">
  <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Generate" onclick="formSubmit()">
  <div id="nameContent"></div>
  <div id="errormsg"></div>
```

Please note that formName itself is Node/DOM element. In order to check its value you have to access its `value` property which is String object for text input fields.

JSBin here: http://jsbin.com/xubibigope/2/

Comment: Added after 'document.getElementById("name")' a '.value' and this fixes my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
 formName = document.getElementById("name");
```

will get the input element. accessing it's value looks like this:

```
 if (formName.value == "") {
```

due to this, `formName` is an object, and `if ( formName == "" ) ...` will end up in the `else` part.
There `nameSentence.innerHTML = formName ;` will do nothing since `formName` is an html element.

```
<div id='errormsg'></div>
<form action='' method='post' onsubmit="formSubmit();return false;">
    <input id='name' type='text' placeholder='Slogan here...'>
    <input id='submit' type='submit' value='Generate'>
</form>
<div id="nameContent"></div>

function formSubmit() {
    var formName, formError, nameSentence;
    formError = document.getElementById("errormsg");
    formName = document.getElementById("name");
    nameSentence = document.getElementById("nameContent");
    if (formName.value == "") {
        formError.innerHTML = "Put your name in!";
    } else if (formName.value.length > 20) {
        formError.innerHTML = "Max. 20 characters";
    } else {
        nameSentence.innerHTML = formName.value;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Working fiddle with alle the stuff corrected [here](http://jsfiddle.net/x0x3y8cw/1/)

Comment: Look at the input. That has a id with 'name'.